# Swift Class Property Of Another Property

Tags: swift, class, properties

I have a question. How can I declare a property of a property in a class? (Not sure if that's how it's called but that's the analogy I think of)

Example: `dog.legs.count` or `lightSwitch.status.turnedOn`

How do I declare `count` or `turnedOn` as properties of `legs`/`status`?

And as a matter of fact, of what types do I declare `legs` and `status` considering that `count` and `turnedOn` are Int, respectively Bool?

Comment: the question is, what are `legs` and `status`? they should be property of type class or a struct

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you please explain or show me what the class `dog` should look like in order to be able to access `dog.legs.count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely up to you:

Just create a class `Legs` or `Status` and add a property `count` resp. `turnedOn` to it. Assign an instance of those classes to the owning class.

Of course, accessing it means to include `Legs` and `Status` in the owning class.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a great example of sensible composition, but:

```
class Legs {
    var count = 0
}

class Dog {
    var legs = Legs()
}

var dog = Dog()
dog.legs.count = 4
```